# Access Ip camera using python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ip-camera

instructions to stream IP Camera video utilizing just python in windows OS

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:*****@198.168.1.***')

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Stream IP Camera OpenCV',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Can you help us understand your issue? Is the code throwing an error? Is the code running fine but you are not able to read the stream?

Comment: code throwing an error

Comment: this is the error send by that code:         ("OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\\projects\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\highgui\\src\\window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'\n",)

Comment: Please take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953069/opencv-error-215size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imshow

Comment: was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that cap.read() does not capture the video/frame. The problem is most likely on line cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:*****@198.168.1.***'). Make sure the ip address of camera and ip address of your computer are properly configured according to documentation.