# pyserial says TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno

I am using a program to track peoples faces through my webcam and move servo motors in the direction the person is. [Source](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/WolfxPac/face-tracking-using-arduino-b35b6b). But when running the software, and the camera detects a face it crashes and gives this error:

```
Connection to arduino...
{72: 327, 379: 634}
X :379
Y :72
x+w :634
y+h :327
506.5
199.5
Center of Rectangle is : (506.5, 199.5)
output = 'X506.500000Y199.500000Z'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jaxon\Desktop\Face Tracking\servo\face.py", line 51, in <module>
    arduino.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Jaxon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 310, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\Jaxon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 65, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'X506.500000Y199.500000Z'
```

Full Code:

```
import numpy as np
import serial
import time
import sys
import cv2

arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
time.sleep(2)
print("Connection to arduino...")


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow('img', 500, 500)
        cv2.line(img, (500, 250), (0, 250), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.line(img, (250, 0), (250, 500), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.circle(img, (250, 250), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 5)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            arr = {y: y+h, x: x+w}
            print(arr)

            print('X :' + str(x))
            print('Y :'+str(y))
            print('x+w :' + str(x+w))
            print('y+h :' + str(y+h))

            xx = int(x+(x+h))/2
            yy = int(y+(y+w))/2

            print(xx)
            print(yy)

            center = (xx, yy)

            print("Center of Rectangle is :", center)
            data = "X{0:f}Y{1:f}Z".format(xx, yy)
            print("output = '" + data + "'")
            arduino.write(data)

        cv2.imshow('img', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
    else:
        break
```

Im stuck and have looked over answers on the error but cannot find a fix.

Comment: did you try `arduino.write( data.encode() )` ?

Comment: thankyou!! this fixed the tracking part but the servo motors dont move

Comment: now it is problem with arduino code, not with Python code.

Comment: or maybe like in original code you should send integer values . Code in your link uses `"X{0:d}Y{1:d}Z".format(xx, yy)` and arduino code has `x = Serial.parseInt();` so it expects also integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My apologized. See print. Change this:

```
data = "X{0:f}Y{1:f}Z".format(xx, yy)
```

to:

```
data = "X{0:d}Y{1:d}Z".format( int(xx), int(yy))
```

The output : output ='X328Y323Z'

Used F-string:

```
 print("output = '" + data + "'")
```

to

```
print(f'output = {data } ')
```

Edit: I fix for print

Comment: Check this out [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055506/python3-cv2-resizewindowimg-500-500-error/72058094#72058094  and [linl]https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=243233

Comment: i prob did this wrong but running it returns  this https://prnt.sc/jKkzpvotY_2c

Comment: See. the anwer for print

Comment: I be back another 8 hrs. If you have any problem.

Comment: thank you your response along with @ChristophRackwitz response putting them both together it is now working!

Comment: @M Rald. You are welcome. I am using Raspberry pi too. I be happier to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You use `pyserial` to send data to an arduino, and `pyserial` complains:

`TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes`

Pyserial wants to be given bytes, not (unicode) strings. Do it like this:

```py
arduino.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

Assuming `data` is of type `str` (`unicode`), this turns it into a binary representation using UTF-8. you could also use `ascii` if you don't have any weird characters in the string.

Comment: Yeah. you are right about encode.. I didn't realized.