# How to display and read a live camera video in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, roboflow

I've been working on a code from the Roboflow team that is suppose to display a live video capture and give it's predictions from the model that I trained, but I encounter an error.

Get webcam interface via opencv-python

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Get the current image from the webcam

```
ret, img = video.read()
```

// Synchronously get a prediction from the Roboflow Infer API

```
 image = infer()
```

// And display the inference results

```
 cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

However I got this error :

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I've seen online saying that my image file location is wrong and that's why I get this error, but I'm confused as it is suppose to be showing a live camera constantly instead of just a still image.

I'm new to programming any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[Roboflow code for webcam](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/roboflow-api-snippets/blob/main/Python/webcam/infer-simple.py)

Comment: That error typically means that whatever image you are trying to display is actually not there. Because of this, its width/height are both probably 0 (meaning no image). I'd double check your infer() function and make sure you are actually passed back an image.

Comment: duplicate of [OpenCV Error: (-215)size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953069/opencv-error-215size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imshow)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk - not a duplicate as the cause is almost certainly different.

Comment: still thinking its duplicate

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I changed that but that didn't solve the problem, I know 0 is for webcam and 1 is for usb camera etc. , I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

As Gunner Stone mentioned in their comment, this likely means that the API is not returning an image (it’s probably giving some sort of error message instead).

I’d recommend backing up a tick and making sure your parameters (Eg model ID, api key) are correct by trying to get a prediction for a single image. Then once you’ve verified that’s working come back to the video inference.

Alternatively, I think you might be able to do

```py
print(resp.read())
```

At line 51 in the linked code, right after the `requests.post` bit to see if the API is returning a specific error message.